# When will isComplete() for a hadoop job be set as true?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

We have a map-reduce set up running on Production. A thread keeps checking if the job is complete. While the job continues to run on the dev setup, we are experiencing frequent unexplained restarts in the Prod setup on aws. I can't find any errors in the tasks or map logs that may have caused the job to terminate. The config files are the same in both the setups.Please help me out with this.

```
if (jobInfo.getJob().isComplete())
{
  // do something
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is getting restarted?

Comment: The job is getting restarted.